# SQL join to row with most recent date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite to join two tables with dates that don't perfectly match up.

For a given group/date in the left table, I want to join the corresponding record from the right table with the a date just before that of the left table. Probably easiest to show with an example.

table1:

```
group     date      teacher
  a     1/10/00        1
  a     2/27/00        1
  b     1/7/00         1
  b     4/5/00         1
  c     2/9/00         2
  c     9/12/00        2
```

table2:

```
teacher    date    hair length
   1       1/1/00       4
   1       1/5/00       8
   1       1/30/00     20
   1       3/20/00    100
   2       1/1/00       0
   2       8/10/00     50
```

Gives us:

```
group     date      teacher    hair length
  a     1/10/00        1           8
  a     2/27/00        1          20
  b     1/7/00         1           8
  b     4/5/00         1         100
  c     2/9/00         2           0
  c     9/12/00        2          50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hair length will always become longer by time, then you could do this:

```
select tablea.teachergroup, tablea.date, tablea.teacher,
       max(tableb.hair_length)
from tablea
join tableb
on tablea.teacher=tableb.teacher
and tablea.date>=tableb.date
group by tablea.teachergroup, tablea.date, tablea.teacher
```

This could work for your sample data, but if hair length could become shorter, you have to :

```
select a.teachergroup, a.date, a.teacher,
       tableb.hair_length
from (select tablea.teachergroup, tablea.date, tablea.teacher,
       max(tableb.date) as tdate   -- last date before group date
      from tablea
      join tableb
        on tablea.teacher=tableb.teacher
       and tablea.date>=tableb.date
     group by tablea.teachergroup, tablea.date, tablea.teacher
     ) as a
join tableb
on   a.teacher=tableb.teacher
and  a.tdate=tableb.date
```

These are the efficient way I could do so far.

Comment: Scratch that. This is much faster on large tables

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some sqlite statements for anyone trying to reproduce this problem:

```
 create table tablea (teachergroup varchar(1), date datetime, teacher int);

 insert into tablea (teachergroup, date, teacher) VALUES 
 ('a','2000-01-10',1),('a','2000-02-27',1),
 ('b','2000-01-07',1),('b','2000-04-05',1),
 ('c','2000-02-09',2),('c','2000-09-12',2);

 create table tableb (teacher int, date datetime, hair_length int);   

 insert into tableb (teacher, date, hair_length) VALUES 
 (1,'2000-01-01',4),(1,'2000-01-05',8),
 (1,'2000-01-30',20),(1,'2000-03-20',100),
 (2,'2000-01-01',0),(2,'2000-08-10',50);
```

Now, the most straightforward query (though certainly not a very performant one) would join the two tables like this:

```
 select * 
 from tablea a 
 join tableb on a.teacher=b.teacher 
     and b.date in 
     (select max(date) from tableb where date < a.date and teacher=a.teacher);
```

Another thing you could do is join the tables a bit more liberally:

```
select * from a join b on a.teacher=b.teacher and b.date<a.date;
```

And then use any technique you would ordinarily use for getting the row that corresponds to the maximum date. (Like putting it into a temporary table, then getting the minimum date using a group by and then joining that back to the temporary table to get the row. I'm sure there are other ways.)

Comment: How could I make the query a bit more performant. I'm going to have to join some large tables.

Comment: Depends on how large! I'd run the queries and see how long they take. What makes me suspect that my first query is not that performant is that it has to do a query for each row in tablea. If tablea is large, then that could take a while. (Though you never know, sometimes there are optimizations under the covers and you can't tell what it's doing.)

Comment: I suspect that a faster way would be to do it the second way I mentioned, which is basically equivalent to Jaugar's second query.

Comment: Tried both your solution and Jaugar's solution in sqlite via python and they took the same amount of time. So I'm going with yours for simplicity.